# Can I delete incremental backups made with Déjà Dup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

After using Déjà Dup for a while, I keep getting this error after every attempt at a backup:

> Backup location is too small.  Try using one with more space.

Could I delete some backups made of certain dates only? For example, could I delete all backups older than a month?

My backup folder contains 372 files, with names like:

```
duplicity-full.20121122T124053Z.manifest.gpg
duplicity-full.20121122T124053Z.vol100.difftar.gpg
duplicity-full-signatures.20121122T124053Z.sigtar.gpg
duplicity-inc.20121122T124053Z.to.20121129T151249Z.manifest.gpg
duplicity-inc.20121122T124053Z.to.20121129T151249Z.vol1.difftar.gpg
duplicity-new-signatures.20121122T124053Z.to.20121129T151249Z.sigtar.gpg
```

Can I delete some of these files safely?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Files associated with full and incremental backups:

A ***full backup*** contains all the data of that backup, and it does not depend on any other backups. It consists of at least three files:

- `duplicity-full.DATE.manifest` (just one)
- `duplicity-full.DATE.volYYY.difftar` (one or more)
- `duplicity-full-signatures.DATE.sigtar` (just one)

If the backup is encrypted, these filenames will have a `.gpg` suffix.

An ***incremental backup*** only contains the differences between a previous backup and itself, it depends on the previous backup, and of its previous backups, all the way until the chain reaches a full backup. It consists of three files:

- `duplicity-inc.DATE.to.DATE.manifest` (just one)
- `duplicity-inc.DATE.to.DATE.volX.difftar` (one or more)
- `duplicity-new-signatures.DATE.to.DATE.sigtar` (just one)

To delete a backup, you can just delete the set of corresponding files. Remember that all subsequent dependent incremental backups will become invalid. You can do this manually, or you can use the `duplicity` command.

## Command overview of `duplicity`:

Here's how to view a set of backups using the `duplicity` command:

```
$ duplicity collection-status file:///path/to/backup
# output truncated for brevity

Found 0 secondary backup chains.

Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Thu Nov 22 12:40:53 2012
Chain end time: Thu Jan 10 14:17:35 2013
Number of contained backup sets: 7
Total number of contained volumes: 358
 Type of backup set:                            Time:   Number of volumes:
                Full         Thu Nov 22 12:40:53 2012               162
         Incremental         Thu Nov 29 15:12:49 2012                 4
         Incremental         Thu Dec 13 09:05:17 2012                10
         Incremental         Thu Dec 20 11:09:12 2012                 9
         Incremental         Thu Dec 27 00:05:55 2012                83
         Incremental         Thu Jan  3 11:07:31 2013                79
         Incremental         Thu Jan 10 14:17:35 2013                11
-------------------------
No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.
```

Here's how to remove backups older than one month, keeping any backups that are required for incremental backups in the last month:

```
duplicity remove-older-than 1M file:///path/to/backup
```

Here's how to remove all backups except the last full backup set, and its incremental backups:

```
duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 1 file:///path/to/backup
```

Here's how to remove all incremental backups except the last full backup set, and its incremental backups:

```
duplicity remove-all-inc-of-but-n-full 1 file:///path/to/backup
```

The [manpage for the `duplicity` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/duplicity) is very informative, take a look.

Comment: Hi, I was reading through the manpage and was hoping to find some mode details regarding the incremental backups. My situation is as follows - according to duplicity collection-status I have 2 secondary and 1 primary backup chain. I could not find details about the difference of the primary and secondary backup chains. In addition to this I'm still not confident I can delete all the incremental backup files listed under each backup chain.

Comment: To actually delete the backup sets, you need to add the argument `--force` so to delete the last full backup set would be:  `duplicity remove-all-but-n-full 1 file:///path/to/backup --force`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks [@Flimm](https://askubuntu.com/users/2355/flimm) : https://askubuntu.com/a/246694/676490
For users like me  that tried `~/deja-dup` instead of `file:///home/flimm/deja-dup` here a example for a username `flimm`

```
duplicity remove-older-than 1M file:///home/flimm/deja-dup
```